# What is EtherBrowser?

Tags: mist

Is EtherBrowser still in development? There appears to be more discussion of Mist thank EtherBrowser.  What is it and how will it change our lives?

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/25xpkt/where_is_the_etherbrowser/

Comment: What is EtherBrowser? Can you provide a link so that those unfamiliar with this have more context?

Comment: found something here https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/25xpkt/where_is_the_etherbrowser/

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're just talking about Mist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears EtherBrowser may have been an early name for what was developed into Mist.

> The Mist browser is the tool of choice to browse and use Ðapps.

Source - https://github.com/ethereum/mist